# Hydro RViz crashes (Groovy not); glibc detected corrupted double-linked list

Tags: rviz, ogre, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`RViz` keeps crashing on one of my Precise machines on Hydro,

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz 
[ INFO] [1399006946.967568547]: rviz version 1.10.14
[ INFO] [1399006946.967639226]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1399006947.346318548, 1099.690000000]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1399006947.346408033, 1099.690000000]: OpenGl version: 4.4 (GLSL 4.4).
*** glibc detected *** /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001782080 ***
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-open.c: 221: dl_open_worker: Assertion `_dl_debug_initialize (0, args->nsid)->r_state == RT_CONSISTENT' failed!
```

(here RViz stops, command returns)

On Groovy on the same machine,

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz 
[ INFO] [1399007035.268979690]: rviz version 1.9.35
[ INFO] [1399007035.269032342]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1399007035.634235376, 1188.425000002]: OpenGl version: 4.4 (GLSL 4.4).
```

.deb versions:

```
$ dpkg -p ros-hydro-rviz | grep Vers
Version: 1.10.14-0precise-20140418-1245-+0000
$ dpkg -p ros-groovy-rviz | grep Vers
Version: 1.9.35-2precise-20140418-0941-+0000
```

[Similar thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/150576/rviz-doesnt-start/) where OP seems to have RViz working from .deb.

---

**Update** Same error occurs with the [latest source build](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/commit/69448a70367f941230935671c64ccbacc0e90917).
But on another Precise machine on Hydro, this doesn't happen. So I'm sure something, maybe in depended libraries from `RViz` on this machine are problematic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159606/hydro-rviz-crashes-(groovy-not);-glibc-detected-corrupted-double-linked-list/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2014-06-29**:
I am getting a corrupted double linked list error for imageview on a 64bit x86 running 12.10 and Hydro. rviz also crashes. Worked fine on 12.04. So me question is is the architecture the same on the different machines.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-08-15**:
Same issue reported here http://answers.ros.org/question/186947/rviz-glibc-detected/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to [the post by @Dereck](http://answers.ros.org/question/88901/rviz-crashes-when-adding-display/?answer=90336#post-id-90336), I worked around this long-persistent issue by the following (not sure what the root cause was though):

```
$ sudo apt-get purge ros-hydro-* && sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

---

Update) On another machine I saw this issue again. Strangely enough, the error doesn't happen when [RViz is run with `gdb`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0